# Not able to use the info via Terminal in the code sample

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am newbie with JS and trying to write a simple code to encrypt and decrypt the info via Javascript, the sample code is below. It is working till the encryption, but I want to take the 'mystr' into the decryption section back, which is however not working. Any clue would be helpful, thnaks!

```
var crypto = require('crypto');                                                                 
var mykey = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', 'mypassword');                                   

const readline = require('readline').createInterface({                                          
    input: process.stdin,                                                                       
    output: process.stdout                                                                      
})                                                                                              


readline.question(`The string to Encrypt?`, (secret) => {                                       
    var mystr = mykey.update(`${secret}`, 'utf8', 'hex')                                        
    mystr += mykey.final('hex');                                                                
    console.log(`${mystr}`);                                                                    
   // readline.close()  

     //deencryption
    var mykey2 = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', 'mypassword');                                                                                                                            
    var mystr2 = mykey2.update(mystr, 'hex', 'utf8');               
    mystr2 += mykey2.final('utf8');                                                              

    console.log(`${decrypt}`);                                                                  
    readline.close()                                                                            
})
```

Comment: decrypt is not defined, do you mean mystr2 in this place?

Comment: yes, mystr2 is decrypting it. I also tried providing ```    var mystr2 = mykey.update(mystr, 'hex', 'utf8');               
``` did not work either.

Comment: declare var mystr , mystr out of the loop so you can use it anywhere in the project

Comment: unfortunatly, it does not change anything, the error remains same..

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a decipher:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
})

readline.question(`The string to Encrypt?`, (secret) => {

    //create cipher
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', 'mypassword');
    //encrypt string
    var mystr = cipher.update(`${secret}`, 'utf8', 'hex')
    mystr += cipher.final('hex');
    console.log(`${mystr}`);

    //create decipher
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', 'mypassword');
    //decrypt string
    var mystr2 = decipher.update(`${mystr}`, 'hex', 'utf8')
    mystr2 += decipher.final('utf8');

    console.log(`${mystr2}`);
    readline.close()
})
```

For more infos look here: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/ref_crypto.asp

Comment: Hi Philip, meanwhile I figured it out and tried it as well, still not able to carry over mystr variable to mystr2, still facing the error. Please check the update code, it has decipher part.

Comment: If you replace `${decrypt}` with `${mystr2}` in the third line from below it works for me

Answer (score 0):

look like, it was some silly mistake after adding decipher, it is working now :) thanks all for your comments, it help me to fix it.

Here the working code:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');                                                                                                                                          
var mykey = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', 'mypassword');                                                                                                            
var mykey2 = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', 'mypassword');                                                                                                         


const readline = require('readline').createInterface({                                                                                                                   
    input: process.stdin,                                                                                                                                                
    output: process.stdout                                                                                                                                               
})                                                                                                                                                                       


var mystr = '';                                                                                                                                                          
var mystr2 = '';                                                                                                                                                         

readline.question(`The string to Encrypt?`, (secret) => {                                                                                                                
    mystr = mykey.update(`${secret}`, 'utf8', 'hex')                                                                                                                     
    mystr += mykey.final('hex');                                                                                                                                         
    console.log(`${mystr}`);                                                                                                                                             

    mystr2 = mykey2.update(mystr, 'hex', 'utf8');                                                                                                                        
    mystr2 += mykey2.final('utf8');                                                                                                                                      

    console.log(`${mystr2}`);                                                                                                                                            
    readline.close()                                                                                                                                                     
})
```